# How much to make these subtle scratches disappear?

Tags: repair, paint

I'm considering purchasing a car but it has rather subtle scratches on two spots: [image: two spots]

I don't have extra money to fix the scratches now but in the future, can these be fixed, how and more importantly at what cost roughly?

Comment: I can't really comment on the cost, but as a general rule, it depends on how perfect you want the end result to be. I also cannot (personally) tell at all from  the photo. Something as simple as a good wax job can do wonders for tiny scratches, but it depends on depth.

Comment: Mmh OK, I don't want perfection at all. I just want it to be basically visible only for someone who knows where to find them. In the worst case scenario in terms of depth, any idea of the cost? Is it more like $50 or $200 for instance?

Comment: In terms of depth, it basically depends if the scratches are through the clear coat, color coats or primer costs. If you wanted to do it on your own, you could do it for that range for sure. If you want to get it done, I'd guess probably more. But if course, that's based on my pertussis experience in southern California. It could be more or less in your locality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If just the clear coat is damaged, you can do a wet sanding technique. You can Google "how to buff automotive clear coat" and there are tons of different things you'll find. 
[Clear Coat Buffing](https://www.wikihow.com/Buff-Clear-Coat)

If the damage is to the color coat or deeper, you'll probably want to get it done professionally because the color can be hard to match and getting a nice finish does require some technique.

All of that said, I don't have the most experience on finishing automotive surface on this stack. Others may have better input. Doing it yourself will be the cheapest option, but will require the most time and effort and may result in a bad result depending how well you end up doing it. Getting it done is the easiest, but neither I nor any other user can really comment on the cost thereof.